# Compute yaw of a 2D Vector

Tags: c++, math, vector

I have two 3D points (however the z coordinate is always zero) and want to compute the yaw of the direction vector created from these points. 
I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782647/how-to-get-yaw-pitch-and-roll-from-a-3d-vector) post, and tried the following code based on it:

```
double p1_x, p1_y, p2_x, p2_y;
//initialize vars...

double dx = p2_x - p1_x;
double dy = p2_y - p1_y;

double yaw = atan(dx/-dy);
```

However I seem to get strange results if I test this approach. Moreover this approach does not seem to regard cases with an dy of zero. 
My problem is that I do not entirely know the underlying math, so I have trouble adapting the code.

My question is: How does this approach need to be adapted to return an appropriate yaw? And why isn't it working in ints curent state?

Thank you for your help & regards,
scr

Comment: I didn't see the question about why it's not working in its current state, I would assume it's because your vector is not normalized (length 1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, people will use `atan2` (documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/))

```
double dx = p2_x - p1_x;
double dy = p2_y - p1_y;

double yaw = atan2(dy, dx);
```

This version of your code should give you what you're looking for.

You can then multiply by `180 / PI` if you want a value in degrees.