# Eigen Point-to-Plane algorithm, return quaternions?

Tags: c#, c++, 3d, eigen, quaternions

I am using Eigen to calculate the best fit of a set of points to a plane. What I need to do with this data, is then rotate the set of points so they lie flat, negating the rotation value.

My code is:

```
cv::Point2f plane_from_points(const std::vector<Vector3> & c)
{
    // copy coordinates to  matrix in Eigen format
    size_t num_atoms = c.size();
    Eigen::Matrix< Vector3::Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > coord(3, num_atoms);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_atoms; ++i) coord.col(i) = c[i];

    // calculate centroid
    Vector3 centroid(coord.row(0).mean(), coord.row(1).mean(), coord.row(2).mean());

    // subtract centroid
    coord.row(0).array() -= centroid(0); coord.row(1).array() -= centroid(1); coord.row(2).array() -= centroid(2);

    // we only need the left-singular matrix here
    //  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points

    auto svd = coord.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
    Vector3 plane_normal = svd.matrixU().rightCols<1>();

    float x = plane_normal[0];
    float y = plane_normal[1];
    float z = plane_normal[2];


    float angle = atan2(x, z) * 180 / PI;
    float angle2 = atan2(y, z) * 180 / PI;    

    cv::Point ret(angle, angle2);    
    return ret;
}
```

Then, in C#, I convert the angle values to a quaternion, to rotate my object:

```
  public static Quaternion QuatFromEuler(double yaw, double pitch, double roll)
        {
            yaw = Deg2Rad(yaw);
            pitch = Deg2Rad(pitch);
            roll = Deg2Rad(roll);
            double rollOver2 = roll * 0.5f;
            double sinRollOver2 = (double)Math.Sin((double)rollOver2);
            double cosRollOver2 = (double)Math.Cos((double)rollOver2);
            double pitchOver2 = pitch * 0.5f;
            double sinPitchOver2 = (double)Math.Sin((double)pitchOver2);
            double cosPitchOver2 = (double)Math.Cos((double)pitchOver2);
            double yawOver2 = yaw * 0.5f;
            double sinYawOver2 = (double)Math.Sin((double)yawOver2);
            double cosYawOver2 = (double)Math.Cos((double)yawOver2);
            Quaternion result = new Quaternion();
            result.W = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
            result.X = cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 + sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
            result.Y = sinYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2 - cosYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2;
            result.Z = cosYawOver2 * cosPitchOver2 * sinRollOver2 - sinYawOver2 * sinPitchOver2 * cosRollOver2;

            return result;
        }
```

This gives me:

```
angles: -177 -126
quat: -0.453834928533952,-0.890701198505913,-0.0233238317256566,0.0118840858439476
```

Which, when i apply it, looks nothing like it should. (I expect a roughly 45 degree rotation in one axis, I get a 180 degree flip)

I have tried switching the axes to check for coordinate space mismatch(which is likely), but I cannot get this to work. Am I doing something wrong?

I have checked the 3d points that i pass into the algorithm, and they are correct, so my issue is either in the point-to-plane code, or the quaternion conversion.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 1) The roll also matters (you cannot obtain it from the normal alone - need to sample an off-axis point). 2) Are you sure you are calculating those two angles correctly? 3) Are you sure you are converting from Euler to quaternion correctly? According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Source_Code) it doesn't seem like you are.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: On second thought, maybe my first point is irrelevant to your case, so ignore it for now. But points 2) and 3) I believe are causing problems; you may want to check your math. I don't think that's how you calculate pitch and yaw.

Comment: I will check my quat conversion, thank you! DOES the Eigen function above return radians? If so then this should be correct, I think...  `float angle = atan2(x, z) * 180 / PI;` But I could be wrong here as well...

Comment: I believe it does - most industry math libraries use radians as it is the only mathematically sensible unit. I don't mean a degree-radian conversion error, however - you use another piece of code somewhere to convert `angle` and `angle2` to pitch-yaw, right?

Comment: Just the line above... am i missing a step?

Comment: If you pass `angle` and `angle2` directly to the C# function as pitch and yaw, then **yes** - they are *not* the correct values. See the *2nd* answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782647/how-to-get-yaw-pitch-and-roll-from-a-3d-vector) for how to calculate them correctly

Comment: So if I have: `float x = plane_normal[0];
 float y = plane_normal[1];
 float z = plane_normal[2];
`, I should be using:  

`float yaw = tan(x / (-y));
 float pitch = tan(sqrt(x ^ 2 + y ^ 2) / z);`??

Comment: Not `tan` but `atan`; also I just realized they are using the OpenGL convention (Y and Z are flipped). Use `pitch = asin(z); yaw = atan2(y, x);`

Comment: ok! And then i still need: `pitch = pitch * 180 / PI;` to convert to degrees, correct?

Comment: Yes - but I suggest that you don't convert to degrees inside of your calculation functions, as you'll have to convert back anyway (and that may introduce accuracy problems at certain extremal points). Just convert to degrees when you want to *display* the values for e.g. debugging, and use radians for all the functionality.

Comment: Lastly.. the wiki function for quaternion conversion expects degrees, yes?

Comment: No, radians. Whenever you see math functions in any implementation in any programming language, assume radians.

Comment: Strange, in degrees, it looks very close, radians.. it is still way off.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, by the way! It is much appreciated.

Comment: Ah and one more thing - you need to invert the quaternion to rotate *backwards*. You can do so by reversing the sign of the W component. Also - it doesn't matter if switching to radians gives a result close to that of degrees - you will need to switch to radians anyway since that is what the math library functions use.

Comment: I mean that if I use radians, it looks wrong. With degrees, it looks close to right. Strange.

Comment: If you switch to radians, remember to also remove the backward-conversion code in your C# function: `yaw = Deg2Rad(yaw)` etc

Comment: Ah, got it. thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to calculate the quaternion which rotates one plane to another, simply compute the quaternion that rotates the normal to the other:

```
#include <Eigen/Geometry>

int main() {
    using namespace Eigen;
    // replace this by your actual plane normal:
    Vector3d plane_normal = Vector3d::Random().normalized();
    // Quaternion which rotates plane_normal to UnitZ, or the plane to the XY-plane:
    Quaterniond rotQ = Quaterniond::FromTwoVectors(plane_normal, Vector3d::UnitZ());

    std::cout << "Random plane_normal: " << plane_normal.transpose() << '\n';
    std::cout << "rotated plane_normal: " << (rotQ * plane_normal).transpose() << '\n';
}
```

Also, don't store your angles in degrees, ever (it may sometimes make sense to output them in degrees ...).

And more importantly: **Stop using Euler Angles!**

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. The code above gives me:

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2338 YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY  `

Comment: .. when i use it with my above code function..`Vector3 plane_normal = svd.matrixU().rightCols<1>();`

Comment: Replace `Quateriond` by `Quaternion<Vector3::Scalar>` (or `Quaternionf`, if `Vector3` is always a `float` vector). And of course, all `Vector3d` by your `Vector3` type).

Comment: got it. i ended up creating a new `Vector3f`with: 

`Eigen::Vector3f floor(x, y, z);
 Eigen::Quaternionf rotate = Eigen::Quaternionf::FromTwoVectors(floor, Eigen::Vector3f::UnitZ());`

Comment: .. although this gives me a very different, and much more inaccurate result then what I had previously. Does `Eigen::Vector3d::UnitZ()` give the "floor plane"?

Comment: ah, i had a coordinate space mismatch. this works well. thank you!